# Using robots.txt with Yii Framework

Tags: php, oop, yii, robots.txt

Does the robots.txt file only apply to directory folders or can it be applied to views in OOP?

I am not having success having it apply to either the actual view path (URL) or the urlManager path (URL) within Yii.

Comment: Can't you simply disallow the corresponding URLs for the views? How did you check that's not working?

Comment: I tried doing this but google is still indexing the pages.  Should this be working though?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but you'll find an lengthy explanation with a robots.txt test tool from Google here: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449&expand=test1 (you'll a Google Account)

Answer (score 1):

Robots.txt applies to directories or *web pages*. There is no concepts of views.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Any way to limit search engines from indexing certain pages then?

Comment: Robots.txt will block them reaching certain pages. But it must be a valid URL. They don't see views or anything behind the scenes like that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0osTvxrbYLg

You can create an Robots action in SiteController.
Then render to robots.php in view/sites.

Comment: Hi, the video is not available. please remove it or find it's new link.